# Bootstrap Validator - Two fields, only required to fill in one

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrapvalidator

I am using this validator for Bootstrap 3 :
http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator

I have two fields

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="url" class="control-label">URL</label>
    <input id="url" name="url" type='text' class="form-control" require/>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="url2" class="control-label">URL2</label>
    <input id="url2" name="url2" type='text' class="form-control" require/>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
```

And just only required to fill in one, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/issues/174

Comment: @James So, should I get the value of Field A and B, compare, and the show/hide error prompt when submit form? Isn't there a better way?

Comment: I would do the same thing. Not sure if there is a better way unless the library adds the support for it.